# Why does my form not submit what I want it to?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to submit a javscript generated value.
The script is:

```js
var save = function () {
    var left = document.getElementById("left"); //Get a select box
    var result = document.exchange; //get the form
    result.value = ""; //set it's value to ""
    for (i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
        result.value = result.value + "," + left.options[i].value; //set it's value to the values of the select box, divided by commas.
    }
    result.submit(); //submit the form
}
```

But my form only submits this:

```
{
    "utf8" = > "✓",
        "authenticity_token" = > "9gf3upm65ugEhsNvdcaykjdlg7xZbOyTiWJs79SnY3A=",
        "timespan_id" = > {
        "name" = > ["",
            ""]
    },
        "subgroup_id" = > "369141985"
}
```

The form is generated by my Rails. It looks like this:

```
    <%= form_tag(subgroup_change_timespans_path(@subgroup), {
     id: 'exchange',
     name: 'exchange'
 }) do %> <% timespans_array = @subgroup.timespans.all.map { | timespan | [timespan.name, timespan.id]
 } %> <%= select(: timespan_id, : name, options_for_select(timespans_array), {}, {: multiple = > true,
     : style = > "width: 300px; background-color: #9FE",
     : width = > "300",
     : size = > 20,
     : id = > "left"
 }) %> <%= link_to "<<", {
     anchor: "",
     remote: true
 }, {
     id: "toleft",
     w_command: "add_timespan",
     w_auth: form_authenticity_token,
     w_controller: "subgroups",
     w_id: @subgroup.id.to_s
 } %> <%= link_to ">>", {
     anchor: "",
     remote: true
 }, {
     id: "toright",
     w_command: "rem_timespan",
     w_auth: form_authenticity_token,
     w_controller: "subgroups",
     w_id: @subgroup.id.to_s
 } %> <% timespans_array = Timespan.all.map { | timespan | [timespan.name, timespan.id]
 } %> <%= select(: timespan_id, : name, options_for_select(timespans_array), {}, {: multiple = > true,
     : style = > "width: 300px; background-color: #F99",
     : width = > "300",
     : size = > 20,
     : id = > "right"
 }) %> <%= link_to "save", {
     anchor: "",
     remote: true
 }, {
     id: "save"
 } %> <% end %>
```

But as I told you: 
It just submits the names of two hidden fields:

```
<input name="timespan_id[name][]" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="timespan_id[name][]" type="hidden" value="" />
```

I think, there is something wrong with these two. But I don't get what.
Do you have any Ideas?

---

@Малъ Скрылевъ: It has to be this way.
The form should look like this:
[image]

Comment: you have two select tags defined: `<%= select(:timespan_id, :name ...`

Comment: How does a form have a value?

Comment: @epascarello: what should I set than instead of value?

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to do since a `<form>` does not have a value so there is nothing to set.

Comment: I want to change, what is sent to the server. Or, at least send everyting, that is in the left select box, to the server.

Comment: Well you should be setting a textbox/textarea/input and submitting that to the server...

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution for my Problem:
I had to put the select boxes outside of the form, which removed the this parameter:

```
"timespan_id" = > {
                  "name" = > ["",
                              ""]
```

Then I added a `hidden_field_tag` called 'string' inside the form.
Then at last, I changed my save function to:

```
var save=function()
{
var left = document.getElementById("left");
var result;
result="";
for(i=0;i<left.length;i++)
    {       
    result = result+","+left.options[i].value;
    }    
var string=document.getElementById("string");
alert(result);
string.value=result; 
document.exchange.submit();
}
```